# bootstrap navigation bar side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make a nav bar like this in bootstrap

[image]

I tried this code:

```
<!-- Navigation bar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        
        <!-- Navigation bar content -->
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                
                <!-- Organization name -->
                <a class="brand" href="/">Test</a>
                
                <!-- Tabs -->
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                      <li><a href="index/FLT.do"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> Test</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  
                  <!-- Sign in -->
                  <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#login_modal" data-toggle="modal" >Sign In</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  
                </div>
                <!-- /.Tabs -->
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.Content -->
        
    </div> <!-- /.Navigation bar content -->
    
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
        
            <div class="span2">
                <!-- Left Navbar -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                  <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="span10">
                <!-- Right Navbar -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                  <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
           
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which will result to this:

[image]

I tried also in-line styling but I red in the net that it is not a good practice, I also tried overidding the classes that ruin the bootstrap. It has spaces between. Is't possible to do this with just bootstrap or no inline styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space that you see between columns is called Gutter Width. I had the same problem in one of my projects. If you don't want to modify any CSS, then I suggest you get a customized bootstrap. You can modify the **Grid System**.

Customize Bootstrap at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

Comment: Isn't possible to create an external CSS file to do this?

Comment: It is. But, that would require lot of effort by the way of overriding the styles. May have to deal with css specificity issues if we are overriding since bootstrap css and your external css styles conflict.